# Python to IPTables safest way of altering

Tags: shell, iptables, python, mariadb, captive-portal

Does anybody know what the safest way is to alter IPTables from Python?

For a schoolproject we're building a simple captive portal. When the user is authenticated (via python & mariadb) on the portal, python then sends a command to IPTables to give their IP access.

But what is the best way to execute this? Im sure it's not by putting the exact command in Python. Is it by running a shell script? But how are you then able to send their IP address along in the shell script?

Comment: I think you think that a shell script is a strange thing. It's not. On the outside it's not really any different to any other program. (On the inside it's a collection of shell commands and other programs.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this :

```
import subprocess

ip = get_ip() # you have to create the code to fetch IP in this variable
subprocess.run(["/usr/sbin/iptables", "-A", "-p", "tcp", "-s", ip, "-j", "ACCEPT"])
#                                                               ^
#                                                               |
#                                                      This is a variable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run shell command as Gilles mention or you can use a library like [python-iptables](https://github.com/ldx/python-iptables)

In addition, using ipset is more convenient for this kind of task.

Create ipset like below

```
ipset create allowed_list hash:ip
```

iptables rule will be like

```
iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set allowed_list src -j ACCEPT
```

Adding/removing IP address

```
ipset add allowed_list 10.0.0.1
ipset del allowed_list 10.0.0.2
```